# Plot 3D line on top of surface plot in Octave

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave

I have plotted a surface from some data. In the same plot I want to have a 3D line (I have the [x,y,z] values for the line I want to plot). When I try to do this using plot3(x,y,z) in the same figure, the line is always below the surface.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't know if this problem appears in Matlab as well.

Minimal example:

```
figure;
hold all;

y = x = 0:35;
z = ones(1,36).*0.5;
plot3(x,y,z);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
surf(Z);
```

The result (the blue line is below the surface):

[image: example]

Comment: The OP is finding this a problem in Octave which allows expressions with multiple assignments http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_79.html  I've posted the equivalent MATLAB code in the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer part of your question, you don't get this problem in MATLAB with the following code:

```
figure;
hold all;

x = 0:35;
y = x;
z = ones(1,36).*0.5;
plot3(x,y,z);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8);
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
surf(Z);
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. I guess this is since Octave uses Gnuplot.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with `surf` in Octave, so I used the `mesh` function instead. It is not as pretty, and has different parameters but does allow lines to overlay it:
[image: plot3 line overlaying a mesh in Octave]

I created that with the same code as above but replacing `surf` with:

```
    mesh ((X+8)*2.2, (Y+8)*2.2, Z);
```

Because `mesh` needed its parameters to be scaled up. The result is roughly the same.