# plot line over mesh in octave

Tags: plot, octave, mesh

I'm printing data with the 'mesh' function obtaining something like this:

[image: mesh graph]

Using this function:

```
function plotState(x,y,z)
mesh(x,y,z);
```

I was wondering if there is any way to plot a line over this graph. What I want to do exactly is to find the maximum values for each value of 'Previous Speed' and plot a line showing them in the same graph.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem doing this in Octave because Octave does not like to allow multiple values associated with the same location in an array (or plot). [This reference](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_79.html) describes the issue. [A similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835454/plot-3d-line-on-top-of-surface-plot-in-octave) was started recently as well.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much, it was really interesting.